# Pandas dataframes using a function with an index only prints the last element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, soap

Hope you doing well.
I've run into something. Being doing this python script so that I can automate some procedures using SOAP requests. Thing is, when doing `def` it only gives me the last item of the list instead of all the items.
Here's some code (yes, I know some things are in spanish but you get the idea):

```
def recarga():
for i in trx.index:
    print("importe:", trx['Importe'][i], "numero:", trx['Numero cliente'][i])
```

The print is only for reference.

Comment: Did you check the length of `trx`? And just for your information, prefer use `trx.loc[i, 'Importe']` instead of `trx['Importe'][i]`

Comment: Yes, it has five items. It is an excel file that I'm using as a placeholder, instead of using the real deal, just for safer procedure, calling and reading it using pandas.